# How does one convert an ICC characterisation file with no calibration tag into one with a calibration tag

Tags: color-profile

How does one convert an ICC characterisation file with no calibration tag into one with a calibration tag taking the characterisation to be a calibration in order to get a cheap improvement in a computer display for all tools that assume an sRGB display?